How can I repair a previously-working Ubuntu 24.04 install destroyed after dual-boot Windows 11 installation finished?
I was having a perfectly working installation of an Ubuntu 24.04 on a Lenovo laptop.
I tried to make it dual-boot with Win11 (same hard-drive, no external hard-drives involved in any part of the below process).
I resized the home partition to have some empty space for Win11 using a live USB flash drive of Ubuntu 24.04.
I then created a flash-USB with Windows 11 and proceeded to install it on the empty space.
This worked fine, Windows 11 started up.
When I wanted to restart in order to access the Ubuntu distribution, disaster.
grub> terminal waiting for a command and on top of it the message: Minimal BASH-like editing is supported. For the first word ....
I tried searching for the internet for what I did wrong.
The youtube tutorial for installing dual-boot (Win alongside an existing Linux install) I was following simply logged-in into its Linux distro. I cannot do it.
What I tried.
I tried to change the boot order inside BIOS, to no avail.
I tried to use in a live-session of Ubuntu 24.04 (using an USB-flash-drive with the Ubuntu 24.04 iso) the `boot-repair`` utility, but that produced NO recommended actions. The pastebin I got is:

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/cwfQCXCHNt/

And copied here:
boot-repair-4ppa2081                                              [20241023_2114]

============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.

sda: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00)
    Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00) is installed in the boot sector of 
                       sda and looks at sector 0 of the same hard drive for 
                       core.img, but core.img can not be found at this 
                       location.
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/FD/sda: /dev/sda already mounted or mount point busy.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.


================================ 0 OS detected =================================


================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: AD107M [GeForce RTX 4060 Max-Q / Mobile] Phoenix3 from NVIDIA Corporation Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, noble, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: NRCN15WW(1.15) from LENOVO
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0003
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0004,0002,0006,2002,2001,2003
Boot0000* EFI PXE 0 for IPv4 (40-C2-BA-45-61-F6)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x2,0x1)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(40c2ba4561f6,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)RC
Boot0001* EFI PXE 0 for IPv6 (40-C2-BA-45-61-F6)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x2,0x1)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(40c2ba4561f6,0)/IPv6([::]:<->[::]:,0,0)RC
Boot0002* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,ccbef867-5269-4962-b764-8316a27b12a2,0x800,0x219800)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)RC
Boot0003* EFI USB Device (VendorCoProductCode)  UsbWwid(ffff,5678,0,9207057C0849452056)/HD(2,GPT,eed3de8a-acd3-4541-ba17-9014c007d874,0xb8b5a0,0x27a0)RC
Boot0004* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,ccbef867-5269-4962-b764-8316a27b12a2,0x800,0x219800)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi) File(.䥗䑎坏S)
Boot0006* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,ccbef867-5269-4962-b764-8316a27b12a2,0x800,0x219800)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC


============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________


Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________


Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________


Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________


fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 953.87 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk identifier: 4BA87BBF-AF82-48D5-858E-77C9EF5334FE
              Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1       2048    2203647    2201600     1G EFI System
nvme0n1p2    2203648 1065248767 1063045120 506.9G Linux filesystem
nvme0n1p3 1065248768 1065281535      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
nvme0n1p4 1065281536 1999087615  933806080 445.3G Microsoft basic data
nvme0n1p5 1999087616 2000406527    1318912   644M Windows recovery environment
Disk sda: 7.54 GiB, 8095006720 bytes, 15810560 sectors
Disk identifier: EED3DE8A-ACD3-4541-BA15-9014C007D874
        Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
sda1        64 12105119 12105056  5.8G Microsoft basic data
sda2  12105120 12115263    10144    5M EFI System
sda3  12115264 12115863      600  300K Microsoft basic data
sda4  12115968 15808511  3692544  1.8G Linux filesystem

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:8095MB:scsi:512:512:gpt:VendorCo ProductCode:;
1:32.8kB:6198MB:6198MB::ISO9660:hidden, msftdata;
2:6198MB:6203MB:5194kB::Appended2:boot, esp;
3:6203MB:6203MB:307kB::Gap1:hidden, msftdata;
4:6203MB:8094MB:1891MB:ext4::;
nvme0n1:1024GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:KXG80ZNV1T02 LS KIOXIA:;
1:1049kB:1128MB:1127MB:fat32::boot, esp;
2:1128MB:545GB:544GB:ext4::;
3:545GB:545GB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres, no_automount;
4:545GB:1024GB:478GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata, no_automount;
5:1024GB:1024GB:675MB:ntfs::hidden, diag, no_automount;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME    FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL                    PARTLABEL
sda     iso9660  2024-08-27-16-23-26-00                                                    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS amd64 
├─sda1  iso9660  2024-08-27-16-23-26-00               eed3de8a-acd3-4541-ba14-9014c007d874 Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS amd64 ISO9660
├─sda2  vfat     3C53-CAEB                            eed3de8a-acd3-4541-ba17-9014c007d874 ESP                      Appended2
├─sda3                                                eed3de8a-acd3-4541-ba16-9014c007d874                          Gap1
└─sda4  ext4     17871899-7ba7-4a70-95ec-874805d8fbbd 3ff734fd-1ef9-4328-bcc2-160d58e7cde3 writable                 
nvme0n1                                                                                                             

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                       Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1                  0 100% /cdrom
efivarfs               30.6K  76% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/sda1              iso9660         ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048,iocharset=utf8



Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the boot.

I cannot mount (using $ sudo mount ...) any partition listed (in a live Ubuntu 24.04 session) with $ sudo fdisk -l: I get the error message: your fstab has been modified but systemd still uses the old version .... Writing and executing: $ sudo systemctl daemon-reload  doesn't do anything and I still cannot mount any partition.
Inside the Windows 11 install, I went to see if Fast-Startup is enabled, and it is enabled, and I turned it off, but as from the comments, I see this is irrelevant.
Inside the Windows 11 install, I opened the Windows cmd and wrote:
$ bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi and later,
$ bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi, both produced the output: operation completed successfully, but they create in the (Windows?)-grub no Ubuntu entry, but only in the BIOS-grub two Ubuntu entries, both of them showing the grub> ... black-screen-of-death output when accessed ...
I am lost and I do not know how to proceed. Do you see any way forward?

You have 2 Ubuntu entries with boot currently set to 0004. Have you tried the other one (0006)? If not, why not? That's likely the one that works and the other is likely a leftover from a previous installation or failed attempt at it. Furthermore, although you should disable Windows Fast Startup when dual-booting, because you're installing Windows after Ubuntu that setting is irrelevant to the issue you're reporting. That is an entire paragraph of irrelevant ramblings about something quite trivial.

@ChanganAuto, hello, thanks. I will remove that paragraph. I tried to log-in into either of the 2 ubuntu ''instalations''. None of them work. There's 2 of them because I wrote inside Win11 cmd the following: $ bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi and then $ bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi, I think?
